# Nexus VPC Peer Link - does it carry unicast traffic?

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-nexus, vpc, port-channel

Read from the doc that the VPC peer link only carry multicast/broadcast traffic under normal circumstances ->

```
The vPC peer link carries control traffic between two vPC switches and also multicast, broadcast data traffic.
```

If I have a primary FW connected to peer switchA as shown below , can a workstation/server connected to peer switchB reach the primaryFW through the peer link ?

[image]

If not, how can the workstation reach the Primary FW then ?

If there is an additional switch which is connected by VPC,  will the traffic from the workstation to the Primary F5/firewall go through the peer link or down the vPC and up again ? (as shown below)

How does the Nexus switch choose which path to use (the red or blue path) ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Nexus switch will use the vPC link as a normal layer 2 trunk if it's the only way to get the traffic to the destination. Cisco has made the Nexus with the intent to prevent bridge forwarding looping and duplicate packets, to make Layer 2 work correctly without needing Spanning Tree Protocol (STP) to do so.

The exception is, if the end hosts are individually connected to either one of the Nexus switches without any redundancy. In your case, if the primary firewall is only connected to one of the Nexus switches, then it will utilize the vPC link to carry traffic to it.

vPC technology provides sharing of: Control plane, configuration and consistency check, vPC advertisements, Spanning-tree, HSRP, IGMP and MAC address tables. All this information is encapsulated in standard Ethernet frames and only sent out on the vPC link. All frames are tagged CoS = 4 for reliable communication.

Good read: https://www.netcraftsmen.com/how-vpc-works/

Cisco official vPC design guide document for all Nexus switches: https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/sw/design/vpc_design/vpc_best_practices_design_guide.pdf

Comment: how does the nexus switch know if an end host is an orphan host and not reachable via its member ports ? by checking mac address table ?

Comment: @Noob vPC technology provides sharing of: Control plane, configuration and consistency check, vPC advertisements, Spanning-tree, HSRP, IGMP and MAC address tables. All this information is encapsulated in standard Ethernet frames and only sent out on the vPC link. All frames are tagged CoS = 4 for reliable communication.

Comment: thanks for the update.  I updated the diagram, In such case which path will the nexus switch choose to go ? through the vpc or peer link ?

Comment: @Noob if the PC is connected to the switch? Then it will go directly from the switch through the Nexus on the left to the firewall. If it's connected to the right Nexus it will use the vPC link between the Nexus switches to the firewall (red path).

Comment: sorry but just to double confirm, the workstation is connected to the right vpc peer, so is it going to use the vpc peer link to reach the primary f5 (red path) or is it going to go down the vpc port-channel to the bottom switch, then up again (blue path)  ?

Comment: @Noob Red patch via vPC link.

Comment: how does the Nexus switch decide when to take the red vs blue path since both path leads to the F5 firewall ? can't find this information in the docs

Comment: @Noob The Nexus switches determine the flow based on the previous mentioned protocols: Spanning-tree, MAC addresses, Routing information, HSRP, IGMP etc. Both switches know which devices are connected to each other.

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply. Not to be nag, but the doc also states the vpc peer link is normally use for carrying broadcast/multicast traffic. Clearly such traffic is a unicast.

Comment: @Noob Yes, since the vPC protocol and advertisements are broadcast/multicast.

Comment: @Noob If you like my answer i hope you will accept it.

Comment: last q..-> so the vpc peer link does carry unicast traffic as well ? just thinking what other scenarios there will be.. kinda worried when I am not sure how will traffic flow

Comment: @Noob You need to look at your switches as one logical switch and not 2 switches. That's how Cisco intended it to work. If you imagine that, the flow always go to only one switch and therefore the flow is much easier to calculate. That is also why port-channels are always recommended to use. And to answer your question: Yes Unicast will also be carried over a layer 2 link, if determined necessary by the Nexus switch.